# java.lang.NullPointerException while running package in TestNG

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am trying to run my .xml (package) file to run test suite. While running it as TestNG Suite i am getting "java.lang.NullPointerException". If i execute two test cases separately then it passes without any error but fails if i try to run package. I am unable to understand whats missing in my code or am i doing something wrong. Please help.

**My TestCase1:**

```
package Teacher;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

public class TestCase1_TeacherLogin {
    public WebDriver d;
    public Properties p;
    File file;
    FileInputStream fis;

  @Test(priority=0)
  public void TeacherLogin() {
     
      //Enter UserName
      d.findElement(By.id(p.getProperty("txt_username_id"))).sendKeys("username");
      
      //Enter Password
      d.findElement(By.id(p.getProperty("txt_password_id"))).sendKeys("password");
      
      //Click on Login Button
      d.findElement(By.id(p.getProperty("btn_login_id"))).click();
      
      String LoginSuccessexp="my system";
      
      assertEquals(d.getTitle(), LoginSuccessexp);
      System.out.println("Your Login Successful");
  }
  
  
  @BeforeMethod
  public void beforeMethod() throws IOException {
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\Software Testing\\testing softwares\\chromedriver.exe");
      d=new ChromeDriver();
      d.get(p.getProperty("url"));
      d.manage().window().maximize();
      d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }
  

  @BeforeTest
  public void beforeTest() throws IOException {
      file=new File("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\IntMarks.properties");
      fis=new FileInputStream(file);
      p=new Properties();
      p.load(fis);

  }

}
```

**My TestCase2:**

```
package Teacher;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestCase2_InternalExaminer extends TestCase1_TeacherLogin{

  @Test(priority=1)
  public void IntExaminer() {
      
      //super.TeacherLogin();
      
      //Click on Int Examiner link
      d.findElement(By.xpath(p.getProperty("link_IntExaminor_xpath"))).click();
      
      //Click on Link Add Absentee Entry
      d.findElement(By.linkText(p.getProperty("link_AddAbsenteeEntry"))).click();
      
      
      //Select Appointed College
      WebElement we=d.findElement(By.id(p.getProperty("dropdown_college_id")));
      Select sc=new Select(we);
      sc.selectByIndex(1);
      
      //Select Pattern
      WebElement we1=d.findElement(By.id(p.getProperty("dropdown_Pattern_id")));
      Select sc1=new Select(we1);
      sc1.selectByIndex(1);
      
      //Select Subject
      WebElement we2=d.findElement(By.id(p.getProperty("dropdown_subjetc_id")));
      Select sc2=new Select(we2);
      sc2.selectByIndex(3);
      
      //Select Paper Type
      WebElement we3=d.findElement(By.id(p.getProperty("dropdown_paper_id")));
      Select sc3=new Select(we3);
      sc3.selectByIndex(1);
      
      //Select Batch No
      WebElement we4=d.findElement(By.id(p.getProperty("dropdown_batch_id")));
      Select sc4=new Select(we4);
      sc4.selectByIndex(1);
      
      //Enter Seat No
      WebElement we5=d.findElement(By.id(p.getProperty("txt_SeatNo_id")));
      JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor)d;
      js.executeScript("arguments[0].value='50027';", we5);
      
      //Scroll Page Down
      Actions ac=new Actions(d);
      ac.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN).build().perform();
      
      //Click on Remove button
      d.findElement(By.id(p.getProperty("btn_remove_id"))).click();
  }
  
}
```

**My XML file/package:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="My package">
<test name="My test">
<classes>
<class name="Teacher.TestCase1_TeacherLogin"/>
<class name="Teacher.TestCase2_InternalExaminer"/>
</classes>>
</test>
</suite>
```

[Execution Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43WIR.jpg)

**My Console:**

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.9.9
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse-1496718797\testng-customsuite.xml

Starting ChromeDriver 2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7) on port 7843
Only local connections are allowed.
FAILED: IntExaminer
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Teacher.TestCase2_InternalExaminer.IntExaminer(TestCase2_InternalExaminer.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@55a1c291: 25 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@482cd91f: 11 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@75f9eccc: 93 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@64c87930: 85 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 17 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@75c072cb: 10 ms
```

Comment: Where do you get the NPE? Can you please post the Stacktrace?

Comment: //Click on Int Examiner link
d.findElement(By.xpath(p.getProperty("link_IntExaminor_xpath"))).click();

Comment: Any help/solution sir?